# Display tinymce textarea dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, tinymce

I have a drop down list that when a selection is made will insert a bunch of elements within a form to the DOM using ajax, within this form I have textareas that I wish to be TinyMCE textareas.

I have this inside of my HTML head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"

     });
</script>
```

This is the ajax function that I use to add a bunch of elements, this is working how I need it to.

```
function getSecFacility(facsecid, facid) {

    $("#new_section_form").hide();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "facility_section_information.php",
    data: 'facility_section_id='+facsecid+'&facility_id='+facid,

    success: function(data){
            $("#selected_fac_section").html(data);
    }
   });
   //loadTinyMCEEditor();
};
```

I have other textareas on my page that are not inserted by ajax and they display as WYSIWYG editors no problem, the issue is when I am adding in new elements.

I have checked several other questions trying to find an "answer" but nothing is working.

I tried to make a function called `loadTinyMCEEditor()` that I was calling within my `getSecFacility()` function after my ajax call. Within this function I was trying to reinitialize tinyMCE for these newly added textareas.

`loadTinyMCEEditor()` looks like this:

```
function loadTinyMCEEditor() {
    tinyMCE.init({
            selector: "textarea"
      });
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'test'); //test is the class name I gave this textarea
    //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, 'test'); //tried setting the bool to true..even tried without these lines
}
```

No matter what I try I cannot seem to get it to work with newly inserted textareas, How can I get these textareas to be TinyMCE textareas?

**EDIT**

I can now view the editor to my newly added textareas after I make a selection from my drop down list. However this only works once, if I make a second selection the new textareas only display as plain textareas. Here is what I changed in my ajax function:

```
function getFacSecFacility(facsecid, facid) {

    $("#new_section_form").hide();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "facility_section_information.php",
    data: 'facility_section_id='+facsecid+'&facility_id='+facid,

    success: function(data){
            $("#selected_fac_section").html(data);
            loadTinyMCEEditor();
    }
   });
};


function loadTinyMCEEditor() {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"
    });
}
```

So after I make a selection this ajax function will run and display new textareas + other form information and I re-initialize the tinymce editors but for some reason this is only working once.

What should I change/do so that I can make multiple selection from my drop down list so that each time the new textareas will display as tinymce textareas?

Comment: After answering your question, I realized. What is your "bunch of elements", as I see no elements added in your ajax call?

Comment: @ilter `facility_section_information.php` outputs html elements into a `div` that I have with the `id="selected_fac_section"`.

Comment: And where is your auto inserted textarea exactly?

Comment: The textarea is within a form that I have which is in `facility_section_information.php`.

Comment: I mean,  how do you access it? Does it have a selector of some kind? Id, class, anything? If you initialize your newly created textarea with tinymce with textarea selector, you will be reinitializing all the existing tinymce editors on the page, too. That is not what you want. That's why you should use a different selector for the newly created textarea in order to just select it this time. I hope it makes sense. You should init it in the success calback. I hope you got why from my answer. Try that and come back. Then we'll see what to do next ;)

Comment: Where are you on that? Have you managed to make this work?

Comment: @ilter I think it's halfway there. I am able to view the editor to my newly elements when I make a selection from my drop down list. However, if I make a second selection afterwards the editors do not display. I am stuck trying to get it to work no matter how many selections I make. See update in my question to see what my ajax function looks like now.

Comment: You really need to create a jsfiddle for that. I am losing track every time you post a new message :)

Comment: @ilter I would've already made one but I can't make something meaningful because of the PHP

Comment: You can fake the return data with a json object, always. That should't stop you :)

Comment: I have the same problem (shows only on the first dynamically added element), did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent` with your incoming ajax-content. In your callback try:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);
```

Greetings

Comment: Hey! finally some help, I tried adding that after `$("#selected_fac_section").html(data);` still nothing is showing up. That is where you were referring too, correct?

Comment: I dont understand. Did you try? It's a core-method of tinymce. If there are more than one editor you get it and set new content by `tinymce.EditorManager.get('yourEditorId').setContent(data);`

Comment: If you use `$('yourEditorId').html(data)`you'll overwrite the intern structure of the editor content, which is more than the pure html and nothing works.

Comment: Yes I tried what you had suggested in your answer you posted. I also tried adding `tinymce.EditorManager.get('withMyIdHere').setContent(data);` and I still cannot get it to display.

Comment: Before you do, like I suggested, you have to init your tinymce by `tinymce .init(...)`

Comment: Are you sure, your ajax-data comes in?

Comment: for using the Editor-ID you write it without "#".

Comment: Yeah, ajax-data comes in because it displays just my plain textareas as well as some input fields but it doesnt show as a tinyMCE textarea. I tried to select the editor without the "#" still no luck...

Comment: I updated my answer to illustrate where I am stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert `#selected_fac_section` to a tinymce editor, you should call the init function of tinymce in your success function. Ajax calls are async unless you define otherwise. So, if you try to initialize the textarea outside of the ajax call, there still won't be a textarea to decorate with tinymce because the ajax call hasn't been finished yet. Use the id value for the selector this time and you should be good to go.

I am writing this from my phone so writing code here is a pain. Sorry for that. Just wanted to help you out quickly after seing you comment on my another answer. Will check this thread first thing in the morning to make sure if you need more help.

Comment: No worries and no rush, I am also kinda busy atm, I appreciate the help - I am quite new to TinyMCE - I will also get back to this and reply when I can review it.

Comment: Ok then. I will sleep now :)

Comment: I don't want to convert `#selected_fac_section` to a tinymce editor because that is just a div element where I dump a bunch of PHP output from facility_section_information.php including a form where the textarea I with to convert resides. After I do `$("#selected_fac_section").html(data);` could/should I also be doing something like `$("#myTextAreaID").html(data);` to then init tinymce editor? Sorry I am also quite new to Ajax and all of this for that matter, so I am probably doing things in a not so great manner.