# Cannot render a dynamically added textarea as TinyMCE 4.1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4

I have a form where I statically create a TinyMCE editor which works fine.

Now, I want to dynamically add a textarea which I want to render as a TinyMCE editor.

According to what I found on the net, I wrote the following code:

```
function add_new_agpoitext() {
    $("#agpoitextslist").append(
'<div class="row"> \
    <div class="col-md-8"> \
        <input type="hidden" name="agpoitexts[' + next_agpoitext + '][sequence]" value="' + next_agpoitext + '"/> \
        <div class="form-group textarea"> \
            <label class="control-label" for="agpoitexts-' + next_agpoitext + '-paragraph"><?=__("Paragraphe ");?>next_agpoitext + ":"</label> \
            <textarea name="agpoitexts[' + next_agpoitext + '][paragraph]" class="form-control" placeholder="Texte" rows="5" id="agpoitexts-' + next_agpoitext + '-paragraph"></textarea> \
        </div> \
    </div> \
</div>');

    next_agpoitext = next_agpoitext + 1;

    var textAreaID = "#agpoitexts-" + next_agpoitext + "-paragraph";

    $(textAreaID).ready(function(){
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, textAreaID); 
    });

    return 1;
}
```

And the TinyMCe init function is the following one:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    ....
    setup : function(ed) {

        ...
    },
});
```

So when I call add_new_agpoitext(), tinymce.init() is called and I can see that the textarea id is the right one. 
But the textarea is not rendered as a TinyMCE editor.

What is missing in my code?

I saw this [How to add tinymce 4.x dynamically to textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107547/how-to-add-tinymce-4-x-dynamically-to-textarea), and so I tried to add tinymce.init() function after my append() call but it doesn't change anything and as my original tinymce.setup() is called, I don't think that the problem is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing `next_agpoitext` too soon. You should increment it **after** using it to build the `textAreaID` variable.

Let's say `next_agpoitext` has a value of `3`:

1. You are creating a `<textarea>` with `id="agpoitexts-3-paragraph"`.
2. You increment `next_agpoitext`. So it now has a value of `4`
3. You use the incremented value to build the `textAreaID` variable, which is assigned the value `#agpoitexts-4-paragraph`
4. You are trying to call the `mceAddEditor` TinyMCE command on a textarea that doesn't actually exist in the DOM.

**Edit:** Also, according to the jQuery docs, you are not using [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) properly. The `ready` event only fires for the whole document, you cannot add a listener for it on regular DOM elements:

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the
>   current document, so the selector can be omitted.

In conclusion:

1. Increment `next_agpoitext` **after** building the `textAreaID` variable
2. Remove the `.ready()` call that wraps `tinyMCE.execCommand`

Comment: You are right, that was really stupid. I verified that the 'id' was correct in the 'init()' call but didn't verify that it was correct for the created textarea. Thanks a lot.